# How to divide a very big .obj file?

Tags: 3d, selections, maya, modeling

I have found this very nice 3d model of a city : http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/paris-33983.html

However the model is very big and has lots of streets, buildings etc. whereas I only need a small part of it. 3-4 blocks are enough for me, and I want to remove the rest of the model. How can I do that?

I cannot select with mouse because objects are grouped in a strange way, i.e. all the trees are a group, all the roofs are a group etc.

I'm using Maya but I'm ok with any type of solution with Blender, SketchUp, MeshLab, SolidWorks or anything. Just tell me a way to select and remove parts of this model.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *RMB* (Right Mouse Button) on the canvas and choose **Select All**
2. In the *status line* choose *Select Component Type* ([image: icon]) and under that *Face* ([image: icon]) deselect others
3. Looking from above marque select the are you want too keep. (make sure your slect tool is not set to select only visible faces.)
4. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and marque select everything to invert selection
5. Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>
6. (Optional) Delete history

Comment: Thanks for your help! Strangely some little parts remained over and there, although I'm certain that I accurately done step 2. However, I have done step 3 with the Lasso tool. I can manually delete the remainings, no problem, but still a comment for the reason of this would be useful for future visitors. Thanks again !